# Cancelar ação backspace

Tags: jquery

Fiz o seguinte script

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('html').keydown(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 8)
                {
                    ConfirmarVolta();
                }
            });
        });

  function ConfirmarVolta() {
        if (confirm("Deseja voltar a tela inicial de cadastro de pedido? O progresso no pedido atual será perdido.")) {
            location.href = "pedidoInserir.aspx";
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

E esperei que ao clicar em 'cancelar' no popup, a tela não sofreria go back. Separei a função do gatilho de pressionar a tecla backspace pois ela é usada em outra parte do código. Como posso fazer para cancelar a ação do backspace caso o usuário não confirme?

Comment: Se queres evitar navegar para fora da página acho que tens de cancelar no keydown, senão no keyup é tarde demais.

Comment: @Sergio Alterei para keydown. Independente disso, ainda mantenho o mesmo problema. Apesar do 'return false', ele executa a ação do backspace

Comment: Tens de dar `return`... testa: `return ConfirmarVolta();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que tens de usar o `keydown` para poderes parar o evento e tens de usar `return` do valor da função para desse modo dar `return false;` caso a função dê `false` como retorno.

Testa assim:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('html').keydown(function (e) {
         if (e.keyCode == 8) {
             return ConfirmarVolta();
         }
     });
 });
```

#### exemplo: http://jsbin.com/femacowuka/2/

Comment: Funcionou, mas peguei o código direto do jsbin e no caso, estava como 'keydown' e não 'keyup' como na resposta daqui.

Comment: @RafaelBarbosa pois expliquei certo mas coloquei errado aqui, já corrigí. Obrigado. Bom que está a funcionar.